how to use taiko with cucumberjs for load testing
I am trying to perform load testing on top of the existing and running cucumberjs and takio scripts for my web application. trying to simulate load test on the existing cucumberjs(with taiko)featuress/steps.
unable to run multiple browser instances for the same set of features/steps. working for one browser instance.
